# Error in setting up my Fyne container, not initialized or declared properly

Tags: go, null, containers, variable-declaration, fyne

I am trying to initialize a container for my Fyne GUI,

I declared it globally here:

```
var w fyne.Window
var content *fyne.Container
```

Then I initialized it in main()

```
func main() {
 a := app.New()
w = a.NewWindow("Recursive Noise")

zoomIn := widget.NewButton("+", func() { zoomIn() })
//fmt.Println("print button", zoomIn)

zoomOut := widget.NewButton("-", func() { zoomOut() })
//log.Println("tapped")

content = container.NewBorder(nil, nil, zoomOut, zoomIn, thisImage)

w.SetContent(content)
```

however, I got the following error

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x7ff7d9952c4c]

I also tried

```
content = container.NewBorder(nil, nil, zoomOut, zoomIn, thisImage)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are missing some pieces of your codes, and it is hard to make  the same error in our machines. Also check the stack trace to identify from where the actual error triggering...update your question as well.

Comment: I agree with the above, lots of code is missing. For example `thisImage` is not mentioned anywhere so we cannot see how you initialise that.

Comment: Also, why make the container global? In general it’s good to avoid that.

Comment: I am trying to make the container global so other functions can access it.  Perhaps I should pass it as an argument?